# Standardize then subtract or subtract then standardize?

Tags: standardization, z-score

I have data as follows:

Variable1: baseline score

Variable2: score after treatment

The two variables have the same units. I want to normalize and standardize the scores. For normalization, the baseline score needs to be subtracted from the score after treatment. I will standardize by getting the z-scores. My question is, does it make a difference whether I standardize or normalize first?

Which approach is the correct one (and what difference does it make?):

Option A:

1. standardize both variables separately.
2. subtract the standardized variables (zVariable2 - zVariable1)

Option B:

1. subtract Variable1 from Variable2 ==> creating Variable3
2. standardize Variable3

Thanks!

Comment: What is your research question? Option A removes any change in the mean as a result of treatment. I assume you are interested in change and as such don't want to do this. For Option B, what is your motivation for standardizing? There are known problems (e.g., regression to the mean) for this type of gain (change) score. Residualized change scores are often viewed as superior (e.g., regress the posttest on the pre-test and a treatment dummy variable -- no standardizing needed).